# How to change ajax pagination to load more or infinite scroll functionality

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, infinite-scroll

I located the AJAX pagaination fucntion of a plugin i'm using for wordpress called Events Manager. As of now when clicking on the pagination it loads the upcoming content on a next page .. however i want the loaded content to display under the initial content. So that users can keep scrolling down. Just like infinite scroll with a load more button. Anyone willing to help me out here or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

```
if(!function_exists('em_paginate')){ //overridable e.g. in you mu-plugins folder.
/**
 * Takes a few params and determines a pagination link structure
 * @param string $link
 * @param int $total
 * @param int $limit
 * @param int $page
 * @param array $data If supplied and EM_USE_DATA_ATTS is true/defined, this set of data will be stripped from the URL and added as a data-em-ajax attribute containing data AJAX can use
 * @return string
 */
function em_paginate($link, $total, $limit, $page=1, $data=array()){
    if($limit > 0){
        $pagesToShow = defined('EM_PAGES_TO_SHOW') ? EM_PAGES_TO_SHOW : 10;
        $url_parts = explode('?', $link);
        $base_link = $url_parts[0];
        $base_querystring = '';
        $data_atts = '';
        //Get querystring for first page without page
        if( count($url_parts) > 0 ){
            $query_arr = array();
            parse_str($url_parts[1], $query_arr);
            //if $data was passed, strip any of these vars from both the $query_arr and $link for inclusion in the data-em-ajax attribute
            if( !empty($data) && is_array($data) && (!defined('EM_USE_DATA_ATTS') || EM_USE_DATA_ATTS) ){
                //remove the data attributes from $query_arr
                foreach( array_keys($data) as $key){
                    if( array_key_exists($key, $query_arr) ){
                        unset($query_arr[$key]);
                    }
                }
                //rebuild the master link, without these data attributes
                if( count($query_arr) > 0 ){
                    $link = $base_link .'?'. build_query($query_arr);
                }else{
                    $link = $base_link;
                }
                $data_atts = 'data-em-ajax="'.esc_attr(build_query($data)).'"'; //for inclusion later on
            }
            //proceed to build the base querystring without pagination arguments
            unset($query_arr['page']); unset($query_arr['pno']);
            $base_querystring = esc_attr(build_query($query_arr));
            if( !empty($base_querystring) ) $base_querystring = '?'.$base_querystring;
        }
        //calculate
        $maxPages = ceil($total/$limit); //Total number of pages
        $startPage = ($page <= $pagesToShow) ? 1 : $pagesToShow * (floor($page/$pagesToShow)) ; //Which page to start the pagination links from (in case we're on say page 12 and $pagesToShow is 10 pages)
        $placeholder = urlencode('%PAGE%');
        $link = str_replace('%PAGE%', $placeholder, esc_url($link)); //To avoid url encoded/non encoded placeholders
        //Add the back and first buttons
            $string = ($page>1 && $startPage != 1) ? '<a class="prev page-numbers" href="'.str_replace($placeholder,1,$link).'" title="1">&lt;&lt;</a> ' : '';
            if($page == 2){
                $string .= ' <a class="prev page-numbers" href="'.esc_url($base_link.$base_querystring).'" title="2">back </a> ';
            }elseif($page > 2){
                $string .= ' <a class="prev page-numbers" href="'.str_replace($placeholder,$page-1,$link).'" title="'.($page-1).'">  </a> ';
            }
        //Loop each page and create a link or just a bold number if its the current page
            for ($i = $startPage ; $i < $startPage+$pagesToShow && $i <= $maxPages ; $i++){
                if($i == $page || (empty($page) && $startPage == $i)) {
                    $string .= ' <strong><span class="page-numbers current">'.$i.'</span></strong>';
                }elseif($i=='1'){
                    $string .= ' <a class="page-numbers" href="'.esc_url($base_link.$base_querystring).'" title="'.$i.'"></a> ';
                }else{
                    $string .= ' <a class="page-numbers" href="'.str_replace($placeholder,$i,$link).'" title="'.$i.'"></a> ';
                }
            }
        //Add the forward and last buttons
            $string .= ($page < $maxPages) ? ' <a class="next page-numbers" href="'.str_replace($placeholder,$page+1,$link).'" title="'.($page+1).'">load more</a> ' :' ' ;
            $string .= ($i-1 < $maxPages) ? ' <a class="next page-numbers" href="'.str_replace($placeholder,$maxPages,$link).'" title="'.$maxPages.'">&gt;&gt;</a> ' : ' ';
        //Return the string
            return apply_filters('em_paginate', '<span class="em-pagination" '.$data_atts.'>'.$string.'</span>');
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the plugin is using custom post types, you might be able to use this plugin as well [ajax-load-more](https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/). You can also create an ajax request yourself.

Comment: This actually worked. I have a bit of difficulty getting the styling done but everything else seems to work. Thnx allot.